# How to generate automatic Id with Commit or Batch Document Firestore REST

Tags: rest, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am creating documents with commit like this way:

```
{
    "writes": [
        {
            "update": {
                "name": "projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents/test/?documentId=",
                "fields": {
                    "comment": {
                        "stringValue": "Hello World!"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "update": {
                "name": "projects/projectID/databases/(default)/documents/test/?documentId=",
                "fields": {
                    "comment": {
                        "stringValue": "Happy Birthday!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The parameter ?documentId= dosen´t work like when creating a single document, if  I left empty I get an error that I must specify the name of the document so how I can generate an automatic id for each document?

Comment: Hi - have you created this as a feature request already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, batch commits with auto generated `documentId` are not possible in the Firestore REST API. As you can see in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document), the Document object should be provided with a full path, including the `documentID`:

> “Name:string
> The resource name of the document, for example projects/{project_id}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}.”

And if it was possible to omit the `documentID`, it would be mentioned in this documentation.

If you would like to have this implemented in the Firestore REST API, you can create a feature request in [Google’s Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0) so that they can consider implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem and discovered that it is still not implemented.

I created a feature request for it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227875470.

So please go star it if you want this to be added.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31449303)